# Interactive subprocess in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I try to use Popen to create a subprocess. What I expect is to use a thread to continuously input something, and read/print the output. Following is my code. It's blocked when I invoke `read`

```
import threading
import subprocess
import time
p = subprocess.Popen('bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

def f():
    while True:
        p.stdin.write(bytes('echo hi', 'utf-8'))
        time.sleep(3)

t= threading.Thread(target=f)

t.start()

p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: I didn't get this to work, but adding a newline at the end of `'echo hi'` and calling `p.stdin.flush()` before the next line seems to be a little more correct.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I did my testing using my mac's `say` command so I didn't have to get everything right at once. When I made the above changes, and used `say` instead of `echo`, it sort of worked. It said "hi". Then it said "say hisay hisay hisay" until I killed it. So, that's not right, but it at least dispatches the command.

Comment: @mwchase thanks, `say` in my computer, too. seems that the problem the that the stdout doesn't work as I expected.